# ¿Crea un programa que solicite al usuario introducir un número entero positivo y lo guarda en una variable?

Tags: python-3.x

**Si lo introducido por el usuario; 1 - NO ES UN NÚMERO, tengo que mostrar en pantalla mensaje indicando. 2 - NO ES UN NÚMERO ENTERO, tengo que mostrar en pantalla mensaje indicando. 3 - NO ES UN NÚMERO ENTERO POSITIVO, tengo que mostrar en pantalla mensaje indicando. Abajo es mi código que claro esta mi dando error, necesito de ayuda para aclarar el tema;**

---

```
while True:

    numero = input("introduce el número que deseas: ")

    if (numero.isalpha() == True):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número")
    
    elif (numero.isdigit() == False):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número entero")
    
    elif (numero < 0):
        print("el valor introducido no es un entero positivo")
    
    continue

break
```

---

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tienes que indentar el código entre el 'while' y el 'break'.

Comment: No me entendiste... lo tienes que indentar en tu código, no en la pregunta...

Comment: Mi sigue dando error, puedes ayudarme, entendió la pregunta arriba ?

Comment: Te lo adjunto en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te vas a liar un poco con los break y continue si estás aprendiendo a programar, y los métodos por defecto de string, quizás solo te sirva `isdigit()` para comparar si es entero, de todos modos te muestro como hacerlo con funciones propias.
En Python es fundamental la indentación, al no emplear llaves, usar 4 espacios le indica al programa qué corresponde dentro de cada bloque.
Usando `while True:` tendrás un ciclo infinito, una forma de terminar el programa es colocando una condición que cambie con el transcurso del bucle, en este caso, si ingresa un número válido.

```
def es_numero(n):
    respuesta = True
    try:
        float(n)
    except ValueError:
        respuesta = False
    return respuesta

def es_entero(n):
    respuesta = True
    try:
        int(n)
    except ValueError:
        respuesta = False
    return respuesta

esNumeroValido = False
while esNumeroValido == False:
    numero = input("introduce el número que deseas: ")
    if (es_numero(numero) == False):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número")
    elif (es_entero(numero) == False):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número entero") 
    elif (int(numero) < 0):
        print("el valor introducido no es un entero positivo")
    else:
        esNumeroValido = True
print("Numero valido: "+numero)
```

Comment: No pensaba de esa manera, muchisimas gracias Marcelo!!!!

Comment: Si te ha servido no olvides marcar la respuesta cómo correcta. Es fácil ayudar cuando compartes el código que has intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indentar el código correctamente. En python, es fundamental.

Por otro lado, en la última sentencia `elif` tienes que convertir la variable `número` a número, ya que la instrucción `'input'` siempre produce un string.

```
while True:
    numero = input("introduce el número que deseas: ")
    if (numero.isalpha() == True):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número")
       
    elif (numero.isdigit() == False):
        print("el valor ingresado no es un número entero")
        
    elif (int(numero) < 0):
        print("el valor introducido no es un entero positivo")
        continue
    break
```